# Delaunay link distance

Tags: mesh, distance

I have a Delaunay mesh region. To start with, I give a simple example here:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];
R = DelaunayMesh[pts];
```

The next step I want to do is to calculate every link length in Delaunay mesh. As I don't need to associate every length to its related points, I have tried to calculate nearest points length to every point, and collect them. But it is too slow because I have thousands of points and each length is calculated twice.

Is there a faster way to get all the link length directly?

Comment: Have you tried using the `PropertyValue[]` function. i.e. for your example `PropertyValue[{R, 1}, MeshCellMeasure]`. This will give you a list of edge lengths over the mesh.

Comment: Thank you, Dunlop, PropertyValue really helps. Cheers, Shuoqi